# Programming in Python - function with 3 values

Tags: python, function, parameters

How should I write a function in python that accepts 3 floating value points as parameters and return true as long as the first 2 parameters are equal within the tolerance of the third parameter?

Comment: Probably wrong, but an if statement: if num1-num2<=num3: return true  else: return false

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty trivial:

```
def within_tolerance(a, b, tol):
  return abs(a - b) <= tol
```